# A coding error occurred while building a web gui with yolo

Tags: python, yolo

```
import torch
import gradio as gr
model = torch.hub.load("./","custom", path="runs/train/exp10/weights/best.pt", source="local")
gr.Interface(inputs=["image"],outputs=["image"],fu=lambda img:model(img).render()[0]).launch()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\whynot_\Desktop\yolov5-master\gradio_demo2.py", line 9, in <module>
    import gradio as gr
  File "E:\Sofware_programming\anaconda3\envs\py3.9\lib\site-packages\gradio\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import gradio._simple_templates
  File "E:\Sofware_programming\anaconda3\envs\py3.9\lib\site-packages\gradio\_simple_templates\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .simpledropdown import SimpleDropdown
  File "E:\Sofware_programming\anaconda3\envs\py3.9\lib\site-packages\gradio\_simple_templates\simpledropdown.py", line 6, in <module>
    from gradio.components.base import FormComponent
  File "E:\Sofware_programming\anaconda3\envs\py3.9\lib\site-packages\gradio\components\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>     
    from gradio.components.multimodal_textbox import MultimodalTextbox
  File "E:\Sofware_programming\anaconda3\envs\py3.9\lib\site-packages\gradio\components\multimodal_textbox.py", line 28, in <module>
    class MultimodalTextbox(FormComponent):
  File "E:\Sofware_programming\anaconda3\envs\py3.9\lib\site-packages\gradio\component_meta.py", line 198, in __new__
    create_or_modify_pyi(component_class, name, events)
  File "E:\Sofware_programming\anaconda3\envs\py3.9\lib\site-packages\gradio\component_meta.py", line 92, in create_or_modify_pyi
    source_code = source_file.read_text()
  File "E:\Sofware_programming\anaconda3\envs\py3.9\lib\pathlib.py", line 1267, in read_text
    return f.read()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 1972: illegal multibyte sequence
```

I tried to change the encoding format, but still got an error:

```
import torch 
import gradio as gr 

with open("./runs/train/exp10/weights/best.pt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f: 
    model = torch.hub.load("./", "custom", path=f, source="local") 
gr.Interface(inputs=["image"], outputs=["image"], fu=lambda img: model(img).render()[0]).launch()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\whynot_\Desktop\yolov5-master\gradio_demo2.py", line 2, in <module>
    import gradio as gr
  File "E:\Sofware_programming\anaconda3\envs\py3.9\lib\site-packages\gradio\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import gradio._simple_templates
  File "E:\Sofware_programming\anaconda3\envs\py3.9\lib\site-packages\gradio\_simple_templates\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .simpledropdown import SimpleDropdown
  File "E:\Sofware_programming\anaconda3\envs\py3.9\lib\site-packages\gradio\_simple_templates\simpledropdown.py", line 6, in <module>
    from gradio.components.base import FormComponent
  File "E:\Sofware_programming\anaconda3\envs\py3.9\lib\site-packages\gradio\components\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>     
    from gradio.components.multimodal_textbox import MultimodalTextbox
  File "E:\Sofware_programming\anaconda3\envs\py3.9\lib\site-packages\gradio\components\multimodal_textbox.py", line 28, in <module>
    class MultimodalTextbox(FormComponent):
  File "E:\Sofware_programming\anaconda3\envs\py3.9\lib\site-packages\gradio\component_meta.py", line 198, in __new__
    create_or_modify_pyi(component_class, name, events)
  File "E:\Sofware_programming\anaconda3\envs\py3.9\lib\site-packages\gradio\component_meta.py", line 92, in create_or_modify_pyi
    source_code = source_file.read_text()
  File "E:\Sofware_programming\anaconda3\envs\py3.9\lib\pathlib.py", line 1267, in read_text
    return f.read()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position 1972: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.